# Translate SQL max() group by to Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a table with two columns: listing and bid. Each listing can get multiple bids. I want to run a Django query that returns the highest bid for each listing.

In SQL I would do this:

```
SELECT listing, max(amount) FROM Bid GROUP BY listing
```

In django I tried this. It only returns the single highest bid in the whole table

```
Bid.objects.values('listing','amount').aggregate(Max('amount'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) these with:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Bid.objects.values('listing').annotate(
    max_amount=Max('amount')
).order_by('listing')
```

If `listing` is a `ForeignKey`, it is however better to annotate that model, so something like:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Listing.objects.annotate(
    max_bid=Max('bid__amount')
)
```

since then these are `Listing` models, and thus the model layer does not "erode".